# Preventing shift key from setting map into zoom mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2, keydragzoom

we have the following problem in a legacy (GMaps V2) application: we show a info window upon clicking on a marker. A pop-up is displayed and the user enters an annotation. If the user presses the shift key (for capitalizing letters), the map goes into "zoom mode" (the hand cursor changes into the arrow cursor, and, should the user move the mouse cursor outside the info window, he sees the red rubber-band rectanlge for zooming). Upon closing the window, the map is stuck in the zoom mode, with the red zoom rectangle showing. This only goes away after the user clicks, drags and the map zooms.

Is there a way to prevent the shift key to set the map mode? (I had a look at the KeyDragZoom library, but this didn't solve the problem.) I also tried many workaround for canceling the events, stop bubbling etc, to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

in this way you can disable keyboard inputs:

```
 var ui = map.getDefaultUI();
 ui.keyboard = false;
 map.setUI(ui);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. This only sets keyboard bindings for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [reference documentation](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/keydragzoom/docs/reference.html). You can specify the `key` which activates the drag zoom:

> key   String  The hot key to hold down to activate a drag zoom, shift |
>   ctrl | alt. Note that the altshift.

So, I would try to set it to `null` or `"alt"`.